# non deterministic garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer, non-deterministic

I have come across that the dispose method in C# is for deterministic garbage collection as you know the object is disposed when that method is called. Can you provide a simple example on non deterministic garbage collection? Does it usually occur under multi-threading situation?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read that?  It's false.  Generally speaking, it's for deterministic *resource* cleanup (like releasing OS handles, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`Dispose` will, generally speaking, not trigger Garbage Collection. Instead, the `IDisposable` interface is for items that need some sort of cleanup - for example, they might have a file handle open on the system, or have taken out a semaphore lock, or something along those lines. If you want to enforce that a garbage collection will happen on an object, the best thing you can do is to ensure that it either drops out of scope or you drop your references to the object.

Notably, if you're interacting with an object that implements `IDisposable`, you should still ensure that `Dispose()` is called on the object before you lose your reference to the object (either with a `using` block, which will also have the effect of dropping it out of scope when you're out of the `using` block, or by explicitly calling `Dispose()` on the object.

To summarize: `IDisposable` and `Dispose()` are NOT about deterministic garbage collection, they're about signaling to objects to let them know that they can clean up after themselves - you're done using them.